# XML Style Sheet Parse Field Get Anything to Left of First Space

Tags: xml

Need help to parse an XML formatted style sheet. In the example below, there is a field called [[RecipientName]] which is the recipients full name. I would like the ability to parse out and return the first name, typically the full name will be something like "John Test" or "John Q. Test" or "John Quack Test".

Anyway, I can get anything to the left of the first space?

```
</head>
<body>
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="10" class="mainbody">
    <tr>
        <td colspan="7" class="header">[[EmailTitle]]</td>
        <td colspan="3" class="header">
            <img class="logo" src="[[CompanyLogoEmailPath]]" alt="Company Logo" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="10">
            <p>Sent on behalf of [[SenderName]] at [[SenderCompany]]</p>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="10">
            <p class="recipientgreeting">Dear [b][[RecipientName]][/b],</p>
            <p>[[EmailBlurb]]</p>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr><td colspan="10">
```

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Your XML sample is not _well-formed_. You should fix this.

Comment: Sorry about that, I was thought I was trying to just put part of it because the XML file itself is 599 rows.  I can't seem to find an upload option to attach the actual XML file.